# Downloading Mozilla Firefox

Tags: software-installation, firefox, mozilla

I'm new to Ubuntu, and I've watched countless videos and read even more posts on how to download Mozilla Firefox and use it as my primary web browser. I had it downloaded and I kept getting the error saying that my profile was not available and that it may be missing or incomplete. Has anyone solved this problem yet? And if so can you give me a step by step process on how to re-download Firefox the right way and have it as my main browser?

Comment: I was under the impression that Firefox cam preinstalled on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Mine came preinstalled with chromium web browser.

Comment: that's very strange. What version of Ubuntu is this and where did you download it?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Version 14.04 LTS, and it came preinstalled on my laptop, a Dell Precision 3510.

Comment: ah, that explains it. See if you can run `sudo apt-get purge firefox` and then `sudo apt-get install firefox`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 okay now what? No firefox icon or anything appeared.

Comment: that should completely removed Firefox and then reinstalled it. Reboot and see if it opens.

Comment: @Zacharee1 And when I go to the Ubuntu start button and select Firefox under applications, I get the "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessable." error.

Comment: have you tried searching that error followed by the work Ubuntu or AskUbuntu? I'm on mobile, otherwise I'd provide links.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I've tried everything, when ever you have a free second and can post those links, can you do so?

Comment: all I was planning on doing was to search what I told you to search.

Comment: @Zacharee1 In that case if you do find anything then please share it with me, still finding nothing.

Comment: How did you 'download' it? And is there a Firefox profiles folder on your system (usually in Home - .mozilla - firefox)? There should be a profiles.ini file and a folder named (eight random characters).default.

Comment: @user3169 I just downloaded it from the website and then extracted the file from it. The web browser would open up and then when I closed it and reopened it, I got the error message I was talking about before.

Comment: Other than what has already been said about the profiles folder, I would uninstall FF (from the Ubuntu Software Center if it shows as installed), and then install it again from the Ubuntu Software Center. Of course you should backup the existing profiles folder(s) first just to be safe. It is hard to say what the OEM could have modified.

Comment: As it says here [*How to configure Ubuntu Linux after it's first installed on your Dell PC*](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN151748/en#Default-Applications) under Software Sources: "Note: We would recommend you stick to the official software centre repository, as it is easy to get this wrong."

Comment: @user3169 Ubuntu came installed on my dell PC.

Comment: @user3169 I did as you suggested and and removed and reinstalled firefox from the USC, and still get the same error

Comment: Then you need to find the profiles folder, and check the path in the profiles.ini file. File locations need to be in the folders as stated in the answer by Panagiotis Tabakis.

Answer (score 0):

### How to run Firefox when your profile is moved, renamed, or deleted.

If you see a "Profile Missing" error message that says, *Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible* it usually means that Firefox can't find or access the profile folder.

### Profile was moved or renamed

If you know where your profile is, try one of the following methods to help Firefox find it.

- Move the profile folder back to its original location
- Restore the profile's original name if you've changed it.
- [Create a new profile using the Profile Manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager). Give it a descriptive name, click on the <kbd>Choose Folder</kbd> button, and then select the profile folder you moved or renamed, before you finish the *Create a new profile* wizard.

### Profile was deleted

If you deleted or lost your profile folder and have no way of restoring it, use one of these methods to create a new Firefox profile:

*Your new profile will not contain settings or user data from your deleted or lost profile.*

- **Method 1: Use the Profile Manager wizard**

Follow the steps in the [Use the Profile Manager to create and remove Firefox profiles](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager) article to create a new profile.

- **Method 2: Manually delete the profiles.ini file**

If you have problems accessing the Profile Manager, you can create a new default Firefox profile by deleting the profiles.ini file, using these steps:

1. Click the `Places` menu on the top right of the screen and select `Home Folder`. A File Browser window will appear.
2. Click the `View` menu and select `Show Hidden Files` if it isn't already checked.
3. Double click the folder marked `.mozilla`.
4. Double click the folder marked `firefox`.
5. Delete (or rename, for example, to profiles.iniOLD) the profiles.ini file.

**Note:** *Instead of deleting the `profiles.ini` file, you can delete (or rename) the folder that contains it. For example, rename the `firefox` folder to `firefoxOLD`. When you start Firefox, a new profile will be created.*

Based on information from [Profile cannot be loaded (mozillaZine KB)](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_cannot_be_loaded).